# Browser shows MySQL error that I don't have a column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

My schema in rails clearly shows that I have the column named "position".

```
  create_table "tasks", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "subject_id"
    t.string   "name",       limit: 50
    t.string   "permalink",  limit: 20
    t.integer  "position"
    t.string   "due_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "tasks", ["permalink"], name: "index_tasks_on_permalink", using: :btree
  add_index "tasks", ["subject_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_subject_id", using: :btree
```

And I added a lambda called `sorted` into my `Task` model:

```
scope :sorted, lambda {order("subjects.position ASC")}
```

And my controller is very basic; I've only done the first definition.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

layout false

def index
  @tasks = Task.sorted
end
```

Now my index.html.erb seems perfect, even though I haven't finished the links at the bottom(Because that's not what the error states).

```
<table>

    <tr class="header">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Subject ID</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Permalink</th>
        <th>Paragraphs</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <%=@tasks.each do |t|%>

    <tr>
        <td><%=t.position%></td>
        <td><%=t.subject_id%></td>
        <td><%=t.name%></td>
        <td><%=t.permalink%></td>
        <td class="center"><%t.paragraphs.size%></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <%=link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => t.id}, :class => 'action show')%>
            <%=link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => t.id}, :class => 'action edit')%>
            <%=link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => t.id}, :class => 'action delete')%>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <%end%>

</table>
```

The error on my browser says: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'subjects.position' in 'order clause': SELECT tasks.* FROM tasks   ORDER BY subjects.position ASC` and it highlights the `<%=@tasks.each do |t|%>`. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope wants to order by `subjects.position`, but you created a table named `tasks`.

Change your scope to:

```
scope :sorted, lambda { order('tasks.position') }
```

Comment: or just `order(:position)`